# Htaccess Redirect Image in Folder to another URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have created a redirect but it doesnt seem to work

I tried both approach below

1st redirect

```
Redirect 301 /images/Dog%food-energy.jpg http://www.dogfoodenergy.com/ProductDetails.asp?323
```

2nd redirect

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Dog%20food-energy\.jpg$
RewriteRule ^images/$ http://www.dogfoodenergy.com/ProductDetails.asp?323 [R=301,L]
```

I have atleast 50 different to be redirected to different url as well. You'll also notice that the image has a space which is converted to %20 when paste on the address bar.

Comment: What is the original full URL of the image you're trying to redirect?

Comment: you can use http://www.dog-food-energy.com for example so it will be like http://www.dog-food-energy.com/images/Dog%food-energy.jpg when paste but originally it is http://www.dog-food-energy.com/images/Dog food-energy.jpg  (without percent)

Comment: If originally it is `dog-food-energy.com/images/Dog food-energy.jpg` then in browser it becomes `dog-food-energy.com/images/Dog%20food-energy.jpg` i.e. `%20` instead of space. However you example is just showing `%` can you clarify?

Comment: yes %20 sorry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule "^images/Dog food-energy.jpg" http://www.dogfoodenergy.com/ProductDetails.asp?323 [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```